# Default Horde schema

Tags: mysql, horde

I've got a dump of a database file from horde in SQL format, however it doesn't contain any CREATE TABLE commands, which is a problem.  Making the tables manually seems a bit pointless yet I can't seem to find a copy of the SQL file to actually create the database.  I did find a copy of the schema but it seems to lack quite a lot of tables.  For reference the insert for one table looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO `turba_objects` (`object_id`, `owner_id`, `object_type`, `object_uid`, `object_members`, `object_firstname`, `object_lastname`, `object_middlenames`, `object_nameprefix`, `object_namesuffix`, `object_alias`, `object_photo`, `object_phototype`, `object_bday`, `object_homestreet`, `object_homepob`, `object_homecity`, `object_homeprovince`, `object_homepostalcode`, `object_homecountry`, `object_workstreet`, `object_workpob`, `object_workcity`, `object_workprovince`, `object_workpostalcode`, `object_workcountry`, `object_tz`, `object_geo`, `object_email`, `object_homephone`, `object_workphone`, `object_cellphone`, `object_fax`, `object_pager`, `object_title`, `object_role`, `object_logo`, `object_logotype`, `object_company`, `object_category`, `object_notes`, `object_url`, `object_freebusyurl`, `object_pgppublickey`, `object_smimepublickey`)
```

Does anyone have/know where I can get the original schema?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: Good point1  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Which OS are you using?
Which version of horde?
Anyway, this should be included in the package, e.g. `/usr/share/doc/horde3/examples/scripts/sql/create.mysql.sql.gz`